# Wanting to trim img src= links

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm wanting to trim img src links from the following.

````
<div><div class="ywj qqw"><div><a href="https://www.example.com/favicon2/1565.xlv"><b><img src="https://www.example.com/fsdfsd/sdfsdf889.jpg"></b></a></div><span class="d205435e0e9495893a49925c01e46a37"></span></div></div>
                                        <b><div><span><div class="mnnusjsddg dfgfd"><div><a href="https://www.example.com/sdfsdf/1479.xlv"><b><img src="https://www.example.com/sdfsdf/123348d52.jpg"></b></a></div><span class="d205435e0e9495893a49925c01e46a37"></span></div></span></div></b>
                                        <b><span><div><div class="mnnusjsddg fdfgdfg"><div><a href="https://www.example.com/sdfsdf/1557.xlv"><b><img src="https://www.example.com/dfsdf/12323f37.jpg"></b></a></div><span class="d205435e0e9495893a49925c01e46a37"></span></div></div></span></b>```
````

Which becomes (one url per line):
`https://www.example.com/fsdfsd/sdfsdf889.jpg`

`https://www.example.com/sdfsdf/123348d52.jpg`

`https://www.example.com/dfsdf/12323f37.jpg`

I was probably on the wrong angle, but was looking at https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/98893-how-delete-all-character-before-certain-word.html and https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/216479-sed-delete-each-line-before-character-after-character.html which wern't quite working.

Comment: "_which wern't quite working_" What did you try exactly and what was the result? Can you share?

Comment: `sed 's/.*[src=.]//; s/[">].*//' sample` didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However it is highly not recommended to process XML/HTML content with regexes, if your sample implies you'll always get src attribute in the first place of img elements, you could use that:

```
grep -E -o '<img src="[^"]+' your-file | cut -d'"' -f2
```

Here, `grep` outputs only part of lines which is matched by the regex. Then you can get rid of `<img src"` part of its output by `cut`ting the lines on the double quote `"` and keeping only the second field.

If you have no control on your HTML content, It would be better to use `xmllint` and then process the output to get only the URLs:

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//img/@src' your-file |
  sed -r 's/\s*src="([^"]+)"\s*/\1\n/g'
```

Comment: This works! thanks Learnt a bit more about xmllint in the process